# Loop in NetLogo

Tags: loops, netlogo

I create some random X And Y Points in net logo , and then I want to set them in some group in how , if every point has a distance equal or less than for example 0.5 , place in a specific group , in c# code is :

```
List<Point> region = new List<Point>();
for (int i = 0; i < points.Count; i++)
{
    int distSquared = Point.DistanceSquared(p, points[i]);
    if (distSquared <= eps) region.Add(points[i]);
}
```

what's equivalent in NetLogo . I want to use Loop for this .
Thanks In advance

Answer (score 3):

Let us assume that your `points` are a turtle breed and `p` is one of them. Then you want

```
points with [distance p < 0.5]
```

This loops through the points and filters them appropriately. The result is an agentset.